# Is it possible in C++ to invoke a function only when a flag in a makefile is set by the user?

Tags: c++, macros, makefile

I am working on a C++ project. I would like to know whether there is any mechanism by which I can specify during compilation (makefile project), that I do not want to invoke certain functions? These functions are special features and it depends on the user whether they should be executed or not.

Thank you very much for any help/suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). The feature you seek is called "conditional compilation".

Example:

```
#ifdef MY_ENABLE_TESTING
testingFoo();
#endif
normalFoo();
```

Now `testingFoo()` will only be executed if you compile your program with `-DMY_ENABLE_TESTING`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I didn't do much c++ programming before, thus I was not aware of this simple yet elegant way of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can define something in the makefile and in the C++ code

```
#ifdef something
// do the function call here
#endif
```

more details can be found on google
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html